# How to obtain $Z(\Sigma_f)=\text{Trace}\ \Sigma(f)$ in TQFT?

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory

I am studying [TQFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory) and have a question on one standard property. 
A remark in Wikipedia (see the link above) says:

> If for a closed manifold $M$ we view $Z(M)$ as a numerical invariant, then for a manifold with boundary we should think of $Z(M) ∈ Z(∂M)$ as a "relative" invariant. Let $f : Σ × I → Σ × I$ be an orientation preserving diffeomorphism, and identify opposite ends of $Σ × I$ by $f$. This gives a manifold $Σ_f$ and our axioms imply
>   $$
> Z(\Sigma_f)=\text{Trace}\ \Sigma(f)
> $$
>   where $Σ(f)$ is the induced automorphism of $Z(Σ)$.

How can one see this formula? A standard way to cut the manifold is to cut it "at the middle" to obtain two manifolds with boundary, each of which is isomorphic to $Σ × I$, but this does not help me get the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cut $\Sigma _f$ "in the middle", as you say, you obtain indeed two manifolds $M_1,M_2$ diffeomorphic to $\Sigma \times I$. For $M_1$ the two embeddings of $\Sigma $ in the boundary are standard, hence the element $Z(M_1)$ of $\mathrm{Hom(Z(\Sigma ),Z(\Sigma ))}$ is the identity.
For $M_2$ the two embeddings differ by $f$, hence  $Z(M_2)\in\mathrm{Hom(Z(\Sigma ),Z(\Sigma ))}$ is $\Sigma (f)$. 
Now the associativity axiom tell you that $Z(\Sigma_f )=\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{Id}\circ \Sigma (f))=\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma (f))$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand the last sentence. Where did you use the associativity axiom and how did you get the trace?

Comment: The associativity axiom tells you that $Z(\Sigma _f)=\langle Z(M_1),Z(M_2)\rangle$, where $\langle \ ,\ \rangle$ is the natural pairing between $Z(\partial M_1)=\mathrm{Hom}(Z(\Sigma ),Z(\Sigma ))$ and $Z(\partial M_2)=Z(\partial M_1)^*$. Now the natural pairing between $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ and  $\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)^*\cong\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)$ is given by $(u,v)\mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(uv)$ .

Comment: Can I ask why your paring is the natural one?

Comment: This is part of the axioms. I suggest Atiyah's beautiful *The geometry and Phisics of Knots*, which is much better than the Wikipedia article.